# Unable To Install scratch2py In Python

Tags: python, installation, pip

When I Tried To Install scratch2py using `pip install scratch2py`It Shows An Error `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` But I Have The Version 14.2 Of It!!

Comment: I think ```c++ cmake tools for windows``` is needed

Comment: maybe you have al older installation too, check how python discover the compiler and the paths

Comment: @Sujay I have c++ cmake tools